# Need help adding a sound effect to my image button in tumblr blog using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have six image buttons on my Tumblr blog that I want to add [this](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/2/1302_1256857798.mp3) sound effect to play when I hover over the image.
Each button is set up like:

```
<form name="mybutton" action="insert link here" method="POST">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 247px; top: 204px;"> 
         <input type="image"  id="button" src="insert image here " onMouseOver="this.src='insert image here'" onMouseOut="this.src='insert image here'"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. I would like to keep it simple if possible. Can someone help me?

Comment: `add sound effect to play when I hover over the image` - you must hate your visitors...

Answer (score 1):

This HTML:

```
<audio id="audioImagePlay" style="display:none">
    <source src="url to your audio source" />
</audio>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
<script>
    //get the button element and attach the onmouseover event handler to it. When mouse over fires execute function playAudio.
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("mouseover", playAudio, false);

    function playAudio()
    {
       //get audio element and initiate play.
       document.getElementById("audioImagePlay").play();
    }
</script>
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: I hope it has some great function since @MarcinOrlowski is right. It's incredibly annoying to hear sounds when you hover over an image. Unless it's a game or something.